# Subsets of a torus that are attainable from a given point by a given distribution (in the differentio-geometric sense)

Tags: smooth-manifolds, submanifold, tangent-spaces

Given is a $M$-dimensional torus and a known $M'$-dimensional [involutive  distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(differential_geometry)) $\triangle$, $M' < M$, on this torus.  (Furthermore, $M'$ is known as a function of $M$.)  If ${\bf x}$ is a point on the torus, the question is whether there is a theory for finding the set ${\cal O}({\bf x})$ of all the points on the torus reachable from ${\bf x}$ by a flow induced by $\triangle$.  (In control-theoretic terms, ${\cal O}({\bf x})$ is the [attainable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_(control_theory)) of ${\bf x}$ under the  $\triangle$.)

The [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)) implies that $\triangle$, being involutive, is therefore integrable. So ${\cal O}(
{\bf x})$ is a submanifold of the torus and is the maximal manifold of $\triangle$.

I am trying, however, to determine something more; i.e., whether ${\cal O}({\bf x})$ intersects a given, known sub-torus of the torus.

What theory would you recommend I study so as to explore this question?